# Show filtered rep everywhere on mini-sites

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, mini-site, facebook.stackoverflow

When you go to the users tab on a mini-site, the reputation shown is their filtered reputation for that mini-sites filtered tags.  Here is an [example](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all). But the rest of the site shows the users full reputation.  Why the inconsistency?  Why not show the users filtered reputation on questions, answers, profile pages, etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Users are the same between Stack Overflow and Facebook Stack Overflow, this is by design.

So, when looking at a user or one of their posts you see their total reputation.  If [Marc B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/118068/marc-b) (the [highest ranked PHP answerer](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/topusers) of the last month) were to answer a [facebook](/questions/tagged/facebook) [php](/questions/tagged/php) question, his total reputation on Stack Oveflow is relevant ([even though he hasn't been very active in Facebook tags](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:118068%20%5Bfacebook%5D%20is:answer)).

However, the `/users` tab is a view onto activity on the site.  It makes more sense to show just the earned rep in Facebook tags on that page, accordingly.

Comment: Why not show both when on a mini-site, with the mini-site rep in parenthesis?

Comment: @OffBySome - there's no space, and it really isn't relevant.  We don't want to encourage people to consider "facebook rep" when answering, commenting, or voting either; nothing good can come of that.