# Filter user's mini-site profile the same way as the mini-site itself

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, profile-page, mini-site

At the moment, there is no difference between:
https://stackoverflow.com/users/27290/margaret
and
http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/users/27290/margaret

Surely it would be a good idea to filter the mini-site's profile to only the same tags as the mini-site allows?  I'm primarily talking about the questions shown; I am not a Facebook dev, so I was surprised to see questions until I realised they were the VBA questions I posted on the main site.

Possibly also having a way of showing "My reputation in this particular subtopic" - the current reputation displayed is for StackOverflow overall, even though the `/users` page displays only reputation garnered from those specific tags.  Yes, we still should show the user's overall site rep as well, but maybe the bigger number should be "My value 'round here"?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103918/show-filtered-rep-everywhere-on-mini-sites

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at a single user showing their activity on all of Stack Overflow is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).    We do not want to encourage tribalism, nor diminish a user's contributions outside of the realm of Facebook.

If you're really interested in seeing what a user has contributed solely in the realm of Facebook, you can use search.  As with all other aggregate views on Facebook.StackOverflow, searches *are constrained* by the mini-site tag filter.

Compare [ifaour on Facebook.StackOverflow](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:337227) with the same search on [vanilla Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:337227).

Comment: Uh, I don't get it. Why does it *not* "encourage tribalism" to have a separate site that filters out all questions unrelated to a particular topic (e.g., Facebook), but *does* "encourage tribalism" to use the same algorithm in filtering user profiles accessed *through* this already filtered "mini-site"? I understand the rationale about not wanting to diminish users' contributions in other areas, but if that were really the case, we wouldn't have mini sites in the first place...

Comment: @Cody - filtering someone's view on another user is a very different thing from filtering a list of questions.  We already have tags (we even already have [wildcards](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/~facebook~+or+fbml)), but don't (and won't) cut down profiles to "just the stuff that counts".  It would be a catastrophic failure (of the "shut the mini-site down" variety) for people to start sorting each other into Facebook & Not Facebook Stack Overflow user groups; the community and subject matter is the same, and should stay so.

Comment: So it's really best to think of the mini-sites as merely providing a preset group of favorite tags? That makes more sense, I suppose. But it seems that filtering *reputation* on the user page to only that earned on questions with appropriate tags is a step on the road to sorting users into Facebook and Not-Facebook groups. It's just not entirely clear to me (even after reading the blog article a couple of times) exactly what things are allowed to change on the mini-sites and what things are not. Filtering lists of questions in a user profile doesn't seem a far leap from filtering earned rep.

Comment: @Cody - ... we don't filter anything on the user page; perhaps I misunderstand?  The best way to think of a mini-site is as a tag filter that applies to *aggregated* data.  If it's one user, you see the whole user; one question, you see the whole question; a list of users or questions, you see them (and some of their properties) filtered by the tag set.

Comment: Hmm, I was referring to this from the blog: `Not only will you be able to see only questions related to Facebook, but the reputation on the user ranking pages will also only show reputation earned on questions tagged Facebook.` My point was it's not just questions that are being filtered; the "Users" page gets the same treatment. I'm sorry if I sound dense here; I guess I'm just missing what seems to be a subtle distinction in the design.

Comment: @Cody - ah, that's referring to the [Users Tab](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/users) ; not a user's profile page.  There reputation change shown is constrained to questions in the tag filter, it does not imply that the users are using Facebook.SO to ask/answer nor that they have used Facebook to register (if they even registered).  I can see why that might be a bit confusing, but it is aggregate data and subject to the same filters as question lists.